# Configure Fail2Ban with bash script

Tags: bash, configuration, sed, scripts, fail2ban

I'm trying to configure the /etc/fail2ban/jail.local config with an bash script. I was thinking to use sed and regular expression to change the sections I need.

```
sed -i "s/^bantime  = 600/bantime  = $1/" /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
sed -i "s/^destemail = root@localhost/destemail = $2/" /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
sed -i "s/^action = %(action_)s/action = %(action_mwl)s/" /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
```

As you can see for bantime, destemail and action I'm able to do so. Only if it matches the exactly. I could be that the bantime, or the destemail is changed, then the script won't work. What can i use to make after the = sign flexable. For example if bantime is not 600 but 700 it will also change using the bash script.

Also there is an section to configure SSH and SSHD:

```
[ssh]

enabled = true
port = ssh
filter = sshd
logpath = /var/log/auth.log
maxretry = 6

[dropbear]

enabled = false 
port = ssh
filter = sshd
logpath = /var/log/dropbear
maxretry = 6

[ssh-ddos]

enabled = false
port = ssh
filter = sshd-ddos
logpath = /var/log/auth.log
maxretry = 6
```

I also want to specify the port I use for SSH or enable SSHD with sed and regular expression. But as you can see when i match on enabled I will change all jails or if I match on port I will change all ports in the config. This is not what I want.

Can anybody assist me with an way to configur Fail2Ban with an script and a flexible way?

Many thanks,
Raoul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the single-line edits you could use

```
sed -e "s/^bantime = .*/bantime = $1/"
```

or, more resiliently

```
sed -re "s/^bantime[[:blank:]]*=.*/bantime = $1/"
```

For the multi-line problem, use line selectors to delimit your edits

```
sed -re "/^\[ssh\]$/,/^\[/s/port[[:blank:]]*=.*/port = $1/"
```

Comment: Thank you very much Zwets! Works Like a charme. I had to make one change to get it working and that is changing -re in to -i.